# Set relations on GroceryCRUD with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I am working on a projecj with codeigniter, and it's my first time using GroceryCRUD, and I need to make that a patient can have any number of reports, I have this on my database.

[image]

Where idpatients is the foreign key.

I am using this on my controller

```
public function reports() 
{
    $crud=$this->grocery_crud;
    $crud->set_table('reports');
    $crud->set_subject('Reports'); 
    $crud->set_language('english');
    $crud->set_relation('idpatients','patients','Patient');
    $output=$crud->render();
    $this->load->view('admin_reports', $output);
}
```

And I get this error

[image]

Any help would be appreciated to fix it, How can I declare the relationship so when I add a new report I can choose the patient from a dropdownbox or something?

**UPDATE**

When I change db_debug for false I get this error

[image]

Comment: Can you debug what is and where `je3b51b9f` come from?

Comment: @Tpojka Hi, I don't have any table called je3b51b9f  so I think is a temp table created by GroceryCRUD Model library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [documentation](http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_relation):

> void set_relation( string $field_name , string  $related_table, string
>   $related_title_field  [, mixed $where [, string $order_by ] ] )
>
> Set a relation 1-n database relation. This will automatically create a
>   dropdown list to the fields **and show the actual name of the field and
>   not just a primary key to the list**.

Which means, it will display the field from the table other then primary key (and you are trying to display field `Patient` which is not present in `patients`).

Solution for your issue - replace `Patient` with `Name` (or some other field which is present in `patinets` table):

```
$crud->set_relation('idpatients','patients','Name');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$crud->set_relation('idpatients', 'patients', 'name');
```

This create a drowpdownList with the name of patients from your table patients

Your problem is "Patient", this column not exist on your table patients, for change the name on view use:

```
$crud->display_as('idpatients', 'Patient');
```

I'm sorry for my English